# Best way to keep track of maximum 5 values found while parsing a stream in Java

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures

I'm parsing a large file, line by line, reading substrings in each line. I will obtain an integer value from each substring, ~30 per line, and need to take the return the highest 5 values from the file. What data structure will be the most efficient for keeping track of the 5 largest values while going through?

Comment: An `int` array (of length 5).

Comment: What should happen if there are duplicates of one of the top 5 numbers?

Comment: If there is a duplicate of the value in position 5 then it can be tossed no issue.

Comment: What if there is a duplicate of the highest number? I'm basically asking if a `Set` would work for this.

Comment: Oh, no in that case a Set wouldn't work, as I would want to store both values separately.

Answer (score 7):

This problem is usually solved with a [heap,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) but (perhaps counter-intuitively) you use a min-heap (the smallest element is the "top" of the heap).

The algorithm is basically this:

```
   for each item parsed
      if the heap contains less than n items, 
         add the new item to the heap
      else
         if the new item is "greater" than the "smallest" item in the heap
            remove the smallest item and replace it with the new item
```

When you are done, you can [pop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#remove--) the elements off the heap from least to greatest.

Or, concretely:

```
  static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> top(Iterable<? extends T> items, int k) {
    if (k < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (k == 0) return Collections.emptyList();
    PriorityQueue<T> top = new PriorityQueue<>(k);
    for (T item : items) {
      if (top.size() < k) top.add(item);
      else if (item.compareTo(top.peek()) > 0) {
        top.remove();
        top.add(item);
      }
    }
    List<T> hits = new ArrayList<>(top.size());
    while (!top.isEmpty())
      hits.add(top.remove());
    Collections.reverse(hits);
    return hits;
  }
```

You can compare the new item to the [top of the heap efficiently,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#peek--) and you don't need to keep all of the elements strictly ordered all the time, so this is faster than a completely ordered collection like a `TreeSet`.

For a very short list of five elements, iterating over an array may be faster. But if the size of the "top hits" collection grows, this heap-based method will win out.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (basically a sorted set), where you drop off the `first` (lowest) element each time you add to the set. **This will dicard duplicates.**

```
SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
for (...) {
    ...
    if (set.size() < 5) {
        set.add(num);
    } else if (num > set.first()) {
        set.remove(set.first());
        set.add(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: `set.last()` will return the highest number. Is that really the one you want to remove?

Comment: @dnault Thanks, I should've looked closer.

Comment: SortedSet violates liskov substitution principle. You should avoid this interface and its implementations.

Comment: @oopexpert Can you explain? I don't see how that's true.

Comment: @oopexpert Nevermind, I found an [article](http://www.codelord.net/2010/11/24/liskov-substitution-principle-violation-spotted-in-the-wild/). Interesting. In this case we are safe though because `Integer#compareTo` is "consistent with equals"

Comment: Sets are never sorted by definition. If you add the "sorted"-property you end up with a list. That is the semantic core of this issue. I know the article. It's a technical view on this. So you may be "safe" on the technical side but not on semantics. To be safe you have to introduce a hidden assumption: "compareTo consistent with equals". Everybody who deals with the interface or uses your algorithm has to have this in mind. What I want to say is: Distortion of reality has a price, doesn't matter if you pay it. If you do not distorte reality you are always safe.

Comment: Banning `SortedSet` implementations is extreme. They are extremely useful, and it's easy to mitigate their drawbacks by following the simple, easy, widely documented, and intuitive practice of making `equals()` consistent with `compareTo()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a LinkedList inserting with a sort order.  each new int, you would check the end to make sure it's in the max. If it is then iterate in descending order and if newInt > the node's int, insert the new int there, and then removeLast() to maintain the length of 5.

Array also works, but you'll have to shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

The Guava library has an [`Ordering.greatestOf`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#greatestOf(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)) method that returns the greatest K elements from an `Iterable` in O(N) time and O(K) space.

The implementation is in a package-private [`TopKSelector`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/TopKSelector.java) class.

Comment: I'm guessing that they don't want to have all of the numbers loaded at once in a single `Iterable`.

Comment: `Iterable` doesn't require loading all elements in memory at once, so I don't see a problem with this.