# Top K Elements with Duplicates

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I was looking for a way to determine the top K elements in an array which contains duplicate values.

Let's say here is an array{1,2,2,3,5,2,6,4,5,2,6,3,5}

I need to determine the index of the top 2 largest elements(1st largest and 2nd largest) in this array :

i.e. the result should be {4, 6, 8, ,10, 12} -> 6 being the largest and 5 being the second-largest element

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you stuck on a specific issue? Also, shouldn't the result be `{ 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 }`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090156/best-way-to-keep-track-of-maximum-5-values-found-while-parsing-a-stream-in-java

Comment: A `for` loop, `max1-list1`, `max2-list2` and a number of `if`-s pop into my mind.

Comment: Here is a quick run-down of how it could be done very easily: 1) Extract the largest and 2nd largest number from the array. This can be done with some simple integer comparisons inside a `for loop`. 2) Iterate over the list again, now checking if the values you extracted in (1) match the current value. If they match, save the current index in some collection (e.g. a `List`). 3) Done. If you show some effort yourself, people are more likely to help you, because it shows that do don't just want your assignment to be done for you.

Comment: No, It's not for an assignment.  For a simple workflow, without duplicates, I was thinking of using minHeap. I am just not able to come around the scenario where duplicates should also be considered so wanted to get others point of view.

Comment: How large is K?

Comment: K is 2. But in this case, K doesn't determine the number of elements that should be in the heap(where we can use minHeap and remove the element if its size is greater than K) as it can include duplicates too.

Comment: I mean - if you need large K values (say  million maximal values), you  should use advanced data structures, but for merely small K (say < 100) it is possible to make simple solution with arrays/lists only

Answer (score 0):

You really could have done something...

Like writing code for finding the maximum value:

```
int[] array=new int[] {1,2,2,3,5,2,6,4,5,2,6,3,5};
int topvalue=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    int v=array[i];
    if(v>topvalue)
        topvalue=v;
}
System.out.println(topvalue);
```

will display

> ```
> 6
> ```

(as value)

Then extending it to collect indices of `topvalue` (that's why it's a good idea to go with an indexed loop). This means minor changes, like not just searching for larger values, but also collecting the occurrences of the current largest one. If a new largest value appears, old indices can be thrown away:

```
int[] array=new int[] {1,2,2,3,5,2,6,4,5,2,6,3,5};
int topvalue=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
List<Integer> topindices=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    int v=array[i];
    if(v>topvalue) {
        topvalue=v; 
        topindices.clear();
    }
    if(v==topvalue)
        topindices.add(i);
}
System.out.println(topindices);
```

will display

> ```
> [6, 10]
> ```

(indices)

Then make it 2. It means that if you encounter a new largest value, you do not throw away the previous one, but pass it down as second largest (both the value and its indices, and start a new collection for the largest indices). And if you encounter something between the largest and the second largest value, that's going to be the new second largest, with a new index-collection. Code is becoming a bit hairy but the changes are not grave:

```
int[] array=new int[] {1,2,2,3,5,2,6,4,5,2,6,3,5};
int topvalue=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int top2value=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
List<Integer> topindices=new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> top2indices=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    int v=array[i];
    if(v>topvalue) {
        top2value=topvalue;
        top2indices=topindices;
        topvalue=v;
        topindices=new ArrayList<>();
    }else if(v!=topvalue && v>top2value) {
        top2value=v;
        top2indices.clear();
    }
    if(v==topvalue)
        topindices.add(i);
    else if(v==top2value)
        top2indices.add(i);
}
System.out.print(topindices);
System.out.println(top2indices);
topindices.addAll(top2indices);
topindices.sort(null);
System.out.println(topindices);
```

will display

> ```
> [6, 10][4, 8, 12]
> [4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
> ```

(first line is `topindices`, then `top2indices`, the second line is the result of `addAll()` and `sort()`)

While the separate `if( == )`s for updating the indices can be appealing, in order to make the thing scale, it would be more convenient to have zero or exactly one conditional block running at a time, because for the general case there will be a loop, and it could simply `break` if everything happened in one block. So the code above needs a bit reorganization, which duplicates some of the code (namely the `add()`s, but simplifies the `if` conditions). `clear()` also becomes creating a new list as with that approach we do not have to think about list getting passed down (in which case `clear()` and reuse would ruin everything):

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    int v=array[i];
    if(v>topvalue) {
        top2value=topvalue;             // passing down
        top2indices=topindices;

        topvalue=v;                     // initialization
        topindices=new ArrayList<>();
        topindices.add(i);
    }else if(v==topvalue) {
        topindices.add(i);              // update only
    }else if(v>top2value) {
        top2value=v;                    // initialization only
        top2indices=new ArrayList<>();
        top2indices.add(i);
    }else if(v==top2value)
        top2indices.add(i);             // update only
}
```

this has exactly the same setup part and output as the previous one, so those are removed. What is important is the pattern, hopefully visible:

1. We check if a brand new largest value is incoming. If it does, the current one is passed down as second largest, along with its indices. Then the new largest value is stored, and also its only index, into a brand new list. If this block runs, no other block will, everything is `else if` below
2. If we haven't encountered a new largest value, we check if it is the current largest value perhaps. If it is, index is stored, and again, no other block will run
3. If the value is clearly not the largest one, we check if it happens to be a new 2nd largest one. If it is, the old one is simply thrown away, and the new one is stored along with it index in a brand new list. These lines are exactly the same ones as in (1.), just operating on `top2...` variables, they could actually pass down the 2nd largest value as 3rd one, should those be collected too
4. The last resort is checking if the value is the current second largest one, and if it is, the index is stored. This block is again a counterpart of (3.), just operating on the `top2...` variables.

And this is the code which could be wrapped into a loop with `k` steps, with two conditions inside: if a new larger value is encountered, than the (n)th largest, it will become the new (n)th largest value and index, after the previous one is passed down as (n+1)th largest (meaning that the (n+1)th largest is passed down as (n+2)th largest, so that will be a loop too). And if the exact (n)th value encountered, its index is stored. And in both cases, the `k`-step loop stops with a `break`:

```
static void topk(int[] array,int k) {
    int[] topvalues=new int[k];
    List<Integer>[] topindices=new List[k];
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++) {
        topvalues[i]=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        topindices[i]=new ArrayList<>();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        int v=array[i];
        for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
            if(v>topvalues[j]) {
                for(int t=k-1;t>j;t--) {
                    topvalues[t]=topvalues[t-1];
                    topindices[t]=topindices[t-1];
                }
                
                topvalues[j]=v;
                topindices[j]=new ArrayList<>();
                topindices[j].add(i);
                break;
            }else if(v==topvalues[j]) {
                topindices[j].add(i);
                break;
            }
    }
    System.out.println("topk("+k+")");
    for(List<Integer> i:topindices)
        System.out.print(i);
    System.out.println();
    for(List<Integer> i:topindices)
        if(i!=topindices[0])
            topindices[0].addAll(i);
    topindices[0].sort(null);
    System.out.println(topindices[0]);
}
```

If you call it as

```
int[] array=new int[] {1,2,2,3,5,2,6,4,5,2,6,3,5};
for(int k=1;k<=3;k++)
    topk(array,k);
```

The output will look as

> ```
> topk(1)
> [6, 10]
> [6, 10]
> topk(2)
> [6, 10][4, 8, 12]
> [4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
> topk(3)
> [6, 10][4, 8, 12][7]
> [4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12]
> ```

(It displays the separate and merged-sorted variants too, just in the first case they are the same)

Comment: I always try to add complete example on Ideone, but somehow today I can't even `System.out.println("Hello World");` there, it dies with an unspecified compilation error and sometimes with runtime error (also without details).